# How to add empty data-columns attribute with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, attributes

I need to add data-columns attribute to use salvattore.js but actually I can't only add it , so I need to not provide a value for this attribute.
This is my starting code :

```
$('#liste-vdl div.view-content').attr("data-columns","0");
```

and produce the HTML:

```
<div class="view-content" data-columns="0">
```

This seem not to prevent to apply css but I would to know if it's possible to get the code as required by salvattore ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Answer is more simple as asking...

```
$('#liste-vdl div.view-content').attr("data-columns","");
```

give

```
<div class="view-content" data-columns>
```

fixed